# Play .WMV with C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, dll, video, audio

Hi I want to play a WMV (Or Video File ) in C# Application..

I Have made software in which when i click file then File menu opens then i select the media file but then when i click on play then file should be played..

so please guide me...

and if any dll is required then please tell me ...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DirectX AudioVideoPlayback library.  It's not the best, but it's pretty simple to use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb324497(VS.85).aspx

Comment: +1. Think this is also the best solution, because DirectX is available on nearly all machines, in contrast to Silverlight.

Comment: when to load the video? inside Form_Load event I get a Loader Lock assertion failure...

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("filename");
```

To start the media file in the default media player.

Or you can use SoundPlayer if you want to control the playing from code.

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("filename");
player.Play();
```

**Edit:** Sorry, `SoundPlayer` is only for sounds.

Comment: Sorry, But SoundPlayer is used only for audio not video and also waw file is allowed in SoundPlayer

Answer (score 0):

on the more complicated but powerful side of things, you could host one of the silverlight players in your app.

http://silverlightviewport.codeplex.com/